# Unknown Column in field list (PHP, HTML, SQLyog)

Tags: php, mysql

I've been on it for about 3 hours now and can't be able to get around this problem. A little help would be appreciated. I'm using PHPmyadmin/SQLYog and html. Whenever I try to enter the data in my Customer Cell Number field I get thus annoying error of:

```
Unknown column 'Cust_Cell_No' in 'field list'
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="manage" class="container">
                <h3><br>Manage Offline Purchases<br></h3>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <form method="post" action="savepurchase.php">
                            <input type="text" class="text" value="Customer Cell Number" name="field1" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Customer Cell Number';}">
                            <input type="text" class="text" value="Movie ID" name="field2" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Movie ID';}">
                            <input type="text" class="text" value="Total Amount" name="field3" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Total Amount';}">


                            <input type="text" class="text" value="Quantity Of Tickets" name="field4" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Quantity Of Tickets';}">  



                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                    <div class="submit-button">

                            <input type="submit" value="CONFIRM">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
        session_start();

    include_once ('E:/Softwares/wamp/www/connection.php');

    $Cust_Cell_No= $_POST['field1'];
    $Movie_ID = $_POST['field2'];
    $Total_Amount = $_POST['field3'];
    $Quantity_Of_Tickets = $_POST['field4'];    

$query = "INSERT INTO `movie_schedule` (`Cust_Cell_No`, `Movie_ID`, `Total_Amount`, `Quantity_Of_Tickets`) values ('$Cust_Cell_No', '$Movie_ID', 'Total_Amount', '$Quantity_Of_Tickets')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

 header("Location: staff.php");
?>
```

Here's my SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `offline_purchases` (
  `Movie_ID` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `Cust_Cell_No` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Quantity_Of_Tickets` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Total_Amount` int(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Cust_Cell_No`),
  KEY `Movie_ID` (`Movie_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `offline_purchases`
--

INSERT INTO `offline_purchases` (`Movie_ID`, `Cust_Cell_No`, `Quantity_Of_Tickets`, `Total_Amount`) VALUES
(5, '+921414468545', 2, 1000),
(1, '+923322267050', 3, 2400),
(2, '+923334644546', 2, 1400);
```

Please also note that I've recently changed the Offline_Purchases_ID Primary key to Cust_Cell_No Primary Key in the Offline_Purchases table and from then on I've been getting this error. Note that: I can easily insert data through SQLyog but inserting through my website gives this error. Please help!

Comment: I am not sure, but can you try by renaming $Cust_Cell_No to $Cust_Cell_No_abc in your php code.

Comment: That did not work, unfortunately!

Comment: for which table you are getting error , "movie_schedule" or offline_purchases ? what's table structure for "movie_schedule" ?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \`offline_purchases\`` but `INSERT INTO \`movie_schedule\``? Last time I checked `offline_purchases`!=`movie_schedule`

Comment: also there is error in insert query, use this : $query = "INSERT INTO `movie_schedule` (`Cust_Cell_No`, `Movie_ID`, `Total_Amount`, `Quantity_Of_Tickets`) values ('$Cust_Cell_No', '$Movie_ID', '$Total_Amount', '$Quantity_Of_Tickets')";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has `INSERT INTO movie_schedule` however your table name is `offline_purchases` - Simply change the table name in the PHP query and this should resolve itself!

May I also recommend taking a look at `mysqli_` as `mysql_` has been deprecated, and also I'd suggest using *prepared statements*.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: That worked actually. I apologize for making an error as dumb as this.

Comment: We've all been coding tired and missed things, I have a couple of stupid questions on StackOverflow!